Does ps able to show only parent processes?
I'm parsing output of ps and I don't need all child processes of parent process
/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -p 1488
 \_ postgres: logger process
 \_ postgres: checkpointer process
 \_ postgres: writer process
 \_ postgres: wal writer process
 \_ postgres: autovacuum launcher process
 \_ postgres: stats collector process

Is there a way to show only
/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -p 1488

either any other way to list all running parent processes except ps instrument?

To list only the parent processes without child processes using the ps command and exclude kernel threads and some system services, you can use the --ppid option along with the -o flag to format the output:
ps --ppid 1 -o pid,cmd

This command will list only the parent processes whose parent process ID (PPID) is 1. The -o pid,cmd option specifies that only the PID and command columns should be displayed.
Another way to do it is you can use pgrep with the -P option to list processes based on their parent PID:
pgrep -P 1

lots of ways to do it, but these are the simplest.

Hm..
By ppid 2 I got only kernel processes.
ppid 1 does it as I want
thank you!
